# Cocos2d-html5 white screen issue.

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-iphone, tizen

I have cocos2d html5 game. It runs good on PC, all browsers, without errors, but on Tizen platform it shows only white screen.
It looks like all update loop works right, but something is wrong with drawing. Stats info and background flash for a moment at starting, but then only empty white screen is shown. No javascript errors.

This behavior begins since 2.2 version. With 2.1.5 I have not this issue.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I have this problem right now, as I'm trying to get back into making a cross platform game. But the below 'accepted' answer hasn't helped me because my project is pretty much blank, and doesn't contain the code below :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just inspected cocos2d-html repo (https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-html5/).

Commit 27f140a13bcd2c4920 added in cocos2d/platform/CCApplication.js some code

```
if(cc.Browser.isMobile){
    ...
    cc._addBottomTag();
}

...

cc._addBottomTag = function () {
    var bottom = document.createElement("div");
    bottom.id = "bottom";
    bottom.style.border = bottom.style.margin = bottom.style.padding =    bottom.style.height = bottom.style.lineHeight = bottom.style.fontSize = "0px";
    document.body.appendChild(bottom);
    window.location.href="#bottom";
};
```

This code is executed only for mobile browsers and causes mentioned issue.